# Why are my cookies spreading too much? More flour?

Tags: baking, chocolate, cookies, flour, butter

My chocolate chip cookie recipe spreads too much, even after I refrigerate the dough overnight. I have looked into the different answers on this site, but nothing seems to be working consistently. I'm wondering if the amount of four I'm using is too little? Should I add some baking powder? I know softened butter helps, but I like the taste of melted better...and I do chill the dough.

Here are the ingredients I use:

- 280g all-purpose flour
- .5 tsp salt
- .5 tsp baking soda
- 1.5 sticks butter (melted)
- 1 C brown sugar
- .5 C granulated
- 1 tbsp vanilla extract
- 1 egg, 1 yolk
- 1.5 C chocolate chips

Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/30254/difference-in-cookie-texture-if-we-use-melted-vs-softened-butter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you could be using too much butter. My recipe for chocolate chip cookies has this:

```
2 c flour  (this is ~240g)
1 c butter
1/2 c sugar
1/2 c packed brown sugar 
2 eggs 
1 tsp b soda
1 tsp salt
1 tsp vanilla
1 or 2 c chocolate chips
```

Melted butter is supposed to make the cookies chewier than using softened. I'd reduce the butter to 1 stick + 2 Tablespoons (or even just 1 stick) and see how that works.

I'm also using twice the salt and twice the baking soda.  If reducing the butter doesn't work then I'd try increasing the baking soda.

The only other thing I can see is maybe the vanilla, which is 3 times what my recipe uses, adds too much liquid, but given that you're using 1 egg + 1 egg yolk compared to my 2 eggs, I think it's unlikely.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try decreasing the butter and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Shannon. That said, if you're interested in trying something with a slightly different flavor, peanut butter will also help your cookies avoid spreading, and can make a tasty addition to chocolate chip cookies. Try adding 1 tbsp of peanut butter to the recipe, if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks! Only issue with peanut butter is if someone is allergic...but I will keep it in mind, maybe I can experiment with an alternative nut butter.