# Will adding whole wheat flour make cookies as chewy as using high gluten flour?

Tags: baking, cookies

I don't have bread flour or gluten and I want to bake choco chip cookies with a chewy texture and hard crust outside as well as inside.

Can I use plain flour and add some whole wheat flour to it to get that chewy texture I am looking for?

Comment: Instead of adding gluten, you can develop the gluten that's already there more: more kneading/mixing/processing. I'm not sure that would give you the texture you want though.

Comment: Hi Aishwar Singh, we already have an old question on making chewy cookies in general, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1. I changed your title to be specifically only about the effects of using whole wheat flour, else it would have been a duplicate, and our site closes duplicate questions.